# How to correctly specify a default value in the Spring @Value annotation?

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations

Initially, I have the following spec:

```
@Value("#{props.isFPL}")
private boolean isFPL=false;
```

This works fine correctly getting the value from the property file:

```
isFPL = true
```

However, the following expression with default results in the error:

```
@Value("#{props.isFPL:false}")
private boolean isFPL=false;
```

**Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 28): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'colon(:)'**

I also tried to use $ instead of #.

```
@Value("${props.isFPL:true}")
private boolean isFPL=false;
```

Then the default value in annotation works fine but I did not get the correct value from the Properties file:

Comment: With `#{}` it is an expression, with `${}` it is a placeholder for a value. The first expression you use will call a method/attribute on a bean called props, the one with the placeholder will try to locate a property named `props.isFPL` in the `Environment`. You should use the latter and you are probably loading your properties in the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you. If I load properties in the wrong way why #{} picks up the correct value?

Comment: Because that is an expression not a placeholder. They are both evaluated in completely different ways.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try with `$`  as follows:

```
@Value("${props.isFPL:true}")
private boolean isFPL=false;
```

Also make sure you set the `ignore-resource-no-found` to *true* so that if the property file is missing, the *default* value will be taken.

Place the following in the context file if using XML based configuration:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

If using Java configurations:

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer   propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
     PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p =  new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     p.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

    return p;
 }
```

Comment: My problem with $ is not ignoring a default value.  The problem is that the value from properties file is ignored

Comment: How are you loading the properties file?

Answer (score 19):

For `int` type variable:

```
@Value("${my.int.config: #{100}}")
int myIntConfig;
```

**Note:** there is no space *before* the colon, but an extra space *after* the colon.

Comment: I don't believe the extra space (after the colon) is needed.

Comment: Seems like old answer. I was able to map int value like any other value. `@Value("${my.int.config:100}")`

Answer (score 9):

The exact answer of your question depends on the ***type*** of the parameter.

for 'String' parameters, your sample code works fine:

```
@Value("#{props.string.fpl:test}")
private String fpl = "test";
```

for other types (like boolean in your question) it should be written in this way:

```
@Value("${props.boolean.isFPL:#{false}}")
private boolean isFPL = false;
```

or for 'Integers':

```
@Value("${props.integer.fpl:#{20}}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Does your Spring application context file contains more than one propertyPlaceholder beans like below:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath*:/*.local.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties" />
```

If so, then property lookup for: *props.isFPL* will only take place for the first property file (*.local.properties*), if property not found, the default value (*true*) will take effect and the second property file (*config.properties*) is effectively ignored for this property.

Comment: This is a known issue since 2012, but not fixed, apparently due to both lack of interest and no clean way of fixing it. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14623 for discussion and some ways to work around it. It's explained in an understandable way by http://www.michelschudel.nl/wp/2017/01/25/beware-of-multiple-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurers-and-default-values/

Answer (score 3):

For a String you can default to null like so:

```
public UrlTester(@Value("${testUrl:}") String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

Comment: From a maintenance point of view I'd rather see `@Value("${testUrl:#{null}}")`.

Comment: That seems to be wrong. For a String `${var:} ` defaults to empty String `""`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you're loading your properties, if you use something like

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />`

Then `@Value` should look like

```
@Value("${isFPL:true}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the default is a string specify like this:

```
@Value("${my.string.config: #{'Default config value'}}")
String myIntConfig;
```

Answer (score -4):

This way of defining defaults works only if we write "value=..." in the @Value annotation. e.g.

**Does not work** : @Value("${testUrl:some-url}" // This will always set "some-url" no matter what you do in the config file.

**Works** : @Value(value = "${testUrl:some-url}" // This will set "some-url" only if testUrl property is missing in the config file.