# Spring Boot conditional property evaluation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-el

I've a URL property injected as `@Value("http://log${RELEASE_NAME:}:1234")`. I now want to change this such that if `RELEASE_NAME` is defined, the URL should be `http://log-${RELEASE_NAME}:1234`; if `RELEASE_NAME` is not defined, the URL should be `http://log:1234`.

What'd be the SPEL to do this? The challenge is to conditionally prepend `-`.

Comment: It is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916598/how-to-correctly-specify-a-default-value-in-the-spring-value-annotation

Comment: @VinhNT Apparently you didn't understand my question.

Comment: With a value properties:
@Value("${RELEASE_NAME?:}") private String propUrl;
Then, your url can be like this:
String myUrl = "http://log" + propUrl + ":1234" as the manual way, I know there is better way to inject it directly in propUrl but I will test it before comment again