# Spring boot `@Value` is always zero, despite default

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using

```
@Service
public class Foo
{
    @Value ("${this.does.not.exist: 10}")
    private static int bar;
}
```

Because the value does not exist in the configuration, I was expecting `bar` to have value `10` but it is `0`.

I also tried `@Value ("${this.does.not.exist: #{10}}")` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916598/how-to-correctly-specify-a-default-value-in-the-spring-value-annotation/44898744#44898744), it's still zero.

Why didn't this work?

Comment: The code looks fine and works fine for me. `#{10}` should also not be needed. Which dependencies (e.g. Spring versions) are you using?

Comment: How are you using class `Foo` - as a Spring bean? This will not work if you create a `new Foo()` yourself (then `bar` will have its default value `0`). Spring will only resolve `@Value` in Spring beans.

Comment: @Jesper I am using it within `@Configuration class ... extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { @Bean public UserDetailsService userDetailsService () {return new Foo ();}` how should I structure this?

Comment: @spraff This doesn't work. You always have to autowire beans so they're created by Spring. Since you're already using @Service, the bean is automatically instantiated and can be used via `@Autowired Foo foo;` (or `@Autowired UserDetailsService foo` since it seems that you UserDetailsService == Foo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we autowire static fields in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938529/why-cant-we-autowire-static-fields-in-spring)

Answer (score 1):

I omitted the `static` keyword in the OP (now edited) and that was the fault.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("${this.does.not.exist: 10}")
    private int val;
```

With the last version of spring-boot (and it should with any other version basically).

So the issue must be elsewhere.

Please check the following:

- Make sure that `Foo` is indeed managed by spring (it finds it in the component scanning process). Otherwise no-one will inject the value.
- Make sure that you're not trying to read the value from constructor or something:
  In spring it first creates the object (and at that moment the value of the field is 0 indeed) and only then triggers a bean post processors for injecting values, autowiring, etc.